# Computer Organization and Architecture

Tags: architecture

A digital computer has a memory unit with 32 bits per word. The instruction set consists of 128 different operations. All instructions have an operation code part (opcode) and an address part (allowing for only one address). Each instruction is stored in one word of memory.

a. How many bits are needed for the opcode?

b. How many bits are left for the address part of the instruction?

c. What is the maximum allowable size for memory?

Comment: @satuon Smells like homework to me.

Comment: I think the `[6 marks]` in line 3, refers to the grading points for this particular problem!

Comment: Make me see a/the [*programming* angle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5):

a. 7 bits, because 2^7 = 128 possible opcodes.
b. 25 bits, because 32 - 7 = 25.
c. 2^25 * 32 bits = 128 MB, because with 25 bits you can address at most 2^25 words and each word is 32 bits long.

Answer (score 3):

I would not give you the ANSWERS but the **HINT** is that

- if there are 128 instructions to be handled by the processor, you should make room for each one instruction, meaning **128 unique** instruction codes for them.
- Secondly, **32 - the above answer** will give you the remaining bits
- Lastly, the total size would be **rows * cols**